# Blackberry image background repeat

Tags: blackberry, java-me, background

In my app i am setting bitmap image of verticalFieldManager but it is repeating.  For setting image i am using

```
VerticalFieldManager vertical=new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_HEIGHT | USE_ALL_WIDTH )
{
    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) 
    {               
       super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
       setExtent(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
    }
};

vertical.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(
    Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "bg_640.png" ) ));
```

It is showing like [image: Grey image is repeating four times]

I am stuck here. Any idea will be apperciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the bg_640.png image file in your question?  That would make it clearer what it's supposed to look like, and maybe why it's not currently working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling

```
vertical.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("bg_640.png")));
```

use [this version of createBitmapBackground(Bitmap, int, int, int)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/decor/BackgroundFactory.html#createBitmapBackground%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

and pass parameters like this:

```
vertical.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("bg_640.png"), 
                       Background.POSITION_X_LEFT, 
                       Background.POSITION_Y_TOP, 
                       Background.REPEAT_NONE));
```